# Unexpected Hash Output

Tags: ruby

I've created a hash through a loop that looks like this.

```
   <% ship_hash = {} %>
     <% @order_preview.fedex_rates.each do |rate| %>
        <% if rate.service_name == "FedEx Ground Home Delivery" || rate.service_name == "FedEx 2 Day" || rate.service_name == "FedEx Standard Overnight" %>
        <% ship_hash["#{rate.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(rate.price.to_f / 100)}" %>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
   <% @order_preview.usps_rates.each do |rate| %>
        <% if rate.service_name == "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day" %>
          <% ship_hash["#{rate.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(rate.price.to_f / 100)}" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

What I am trying to do is simple.  I want to get the output of the keys and values through a block.

```
  >> ship_hash
  => {"FedEx Ground Home Delivery"=>"$9.78", "FedEx 2 Day"=>"$20.59", "FedEx Standard Overnight"=>"$33.78", "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"=>"$5.60"}
```

Ok, that's what I expected...

```
  >> ship_hash.each { |key, value| puts "#{key}:  #{value}" }
```

I get

```
  => {"FedEx Ground Home Delivery"=>"$9.78", "FedEx 2 Day"=>"$20.59", "FedEx Standard Overnight"=>"$33.78", "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"=>"$5.60"}
```

When I thought I would get something like this

```
FedEx Ground Home Delivery: $9.78...
```

On the RubyMonk primer page [here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/10-hashes-in-ruby/lessons/47-hashes-in-and-out) is why I am confused.  I don't get the output I expect!!
I am running the commands from better_errors after I <%=raise %>  after the code generates hash.

I must be missing something, this is basic and unexpected...  Feel free to suggest alternate titles to help future confundos ...

**Update**

Well it sounds like a live shell isn't the place to run these commands, as it only returns the hash itself.  What I am trying to do in practicality is populate a f.select field with both the key and value of the hashes.  Not to change the question too much, but How could I populate the option of a select field so it displays the key and values next to eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in irb (or rails console) and type the following:

```
ship_hash = {"FedEx Ground Home Delivery"=>"$9.78", "FedEx 2 Day"=>"$20.59", "FedEx Standard Overnight"=>"$33.78", "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"=>"$5.60"}
ship_hash.each { |key, value| puts "#{key}:  #{value}" }
```

You'll see the following output:

```
FedEx Ground Home Delivery: $9.78
FedEx 2 Day: $20.59
FedEx Standard Overnight: $33.78
USPS Priority Mail 1-Day: $5.60
=> {"FedEx Ground Home Delivery"=>"$9.78", "FedEx 2 Day"=>"$20.59", "FedEx Standard Overnight"=>"$33.78", "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"=>"$5.60"}
```

What's happening is that ruby is printing to the console the expected output, and then returning the hash itself as the return value.

So you should see the output that you expected in your rails logs. However, the html being displayed is the return value of your `each` statement, which is just the hash itself.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
<ul>
<% ship_hash.each do |key, value| %>
  <li><%= key %>: <%= value %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

This will output the key value pairs of the hash in the form of an unordered list.

Comment: I'm not sure where better_errors and binding_of_caller gems fit in with IRB and rails c, but in that live shell all I get for output when I do ship_hash.each { |key, value| puts "#{key}:  #{value}" }
 is what I posted.

Comment: Try going into an arbitrary folder in your console (not via the live shell), typing irb, and typing those commands again.

Comment: I see.  So the live shell isn't a place to test exactly what you're getting for output of a hash.  That's what it seems like, correct?  I only see the hash itself being returned

Comment: Yes, it appears that the better_errors gem doesn't display print statements.

Comment: I marked that the correct answer, I still have a residual one if you wouldn't mind taking a look at, but it's good to know that better_errors is responsible. I was going mad!

Comment: updated my answer, but it probably should have been a separate question.